# Date Validation not working using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two two date fields - from date and to date, and i need to validate 3 things

- Both the values are entered or not
- Date datatype check
- To date must be greater than from date.

But my script is not working.

can some body please check?

Thanks

```
 function checkBothDates(sender,args)
{
    var from = document.getElementById(sender.From);
    var to = document.getElementById(sender.To);
    var behaviorId =  sender.behavior;
    var from_value = from.value;
    var to_value = to.value; 

    if((from_value == "")&&(to_value == ""))
    {
         args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if((from_value != "")&&(to_value != ""))
        {                       
               if((isValidDate(from_value))&&(isValidDate(to_value)))
               {
                    if(from_value < to_value)
                    {
                         args.IsValid = false; 
                          sender.errormessage = "To date must be greater than or equal to the from date"; 
                    }
               }
               else
               {
                    args.IsValid = false;                
                    sender.errormessage = "Please enter valid dates in both the fields";
                    if(behaviorId != null)
                    {
                       openCollapsiblePanel(behaviorId);
                    }        
               }
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;                
            sender.errormessage = "Please make sure you enter both the values";
            if(behaviorId != null)
            {
               openCollapsiblePanel(behaviorId);
            }        
        }
    }
}

function isValidDate(val)
{

        var format = 'dd/MM/yyyy'
        var regexp = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;                       
        if (!regexp.test(val)) 
        {
           return false;
        }
        else 
        {
           try
            {
                $.datepicker.parseDate(format,val,null);
                return true;                    
            }
            catch(Error)
            {
               return false;                    
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please: post the errors you're getting...

Comment: OK first off, you should look over your code, there's a lot of wasted logic. You check to see if if the from and to are empty and then set args.IsValid to true. Then you check again to see if they're not empty and if they're empty then you set it to false. Basicly args.IsValid ends up being false no matter what.

Comment: Possible issue: white space will cause your Regexp to fail

Comment: Actually, if both the text-boxes are empty then its fine, but if you enter from value than you must enter to value that's why I checked them twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty repetitive, you can shorten a lot of it.

Also note that the regex check is entirely unnecessary, since `$.datepicker.parseDate()` won't accept anything invalid anyway.

```
function checkBothDates(sender, args) {
  var from = parseDate( $(sender.From).val() ),
      to   = parseDate( $(sender.To).val() );

  args.IsValid = false;

  if (from == "" && to == "" || from && to && from <= to) {
    args.IsValid = true;
  } else if (from == null || to == null) {
    sender.errormessage = "Please enter valid dates in both the fields";
  } else if (from > to) {
    sender.errormessage = "To date must be greater than or equal to the from date";
  } else {
    sender.errormessage = "Please make sure you enter both the values";
  }
  if (!args.IsValid && sender.behavior) {
    openCollapsiblePanel(sender.behavior);
  }
}

function parseDate(val) {
  if (val == "") return "";
  try {
    return $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/MM/yyyy', val);
  } catch (ex) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks tomalak,i took your code and used this instead of mine, but even i enter a valid date, it is showing the error. I think thr is some thing wrong with "isValidDate" function.

Comment: @Vin05: Hve you checked that `$.datepicker.parseDate()` is even available?

Comment: Ya, i am getting error TypeError: $.datepicker is undefined. But i have included all the Js scripts(Core,Widget,datepicker & jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.js).

Comment: @Vin05: So your problem is that these scripts do not work. Debug this first. (And please don't ask me how to do this.)

Comment: Hi, I understand I am frustrating you with to many easy questions,but this is the first time I am using J-query, thats why i am not sure what i am doing.But any ways Thanks for your help. I will try to fix this.cheers

Comment: @Vin05: This is the first question I've seen from you. ;-) But with the built-in developer tools in your browser it should be fairly easy to find out why the scripts are not loading.

Comment: Hi, If i enter From value as "17/08/2011" and To value as "14/06/2019".It is still throwing an error. I think when we do if (to < from ) it is just validating days and not not years.

Comment: @Vin05: Ah. You must compare actual date values of course, not strings. See modified answer.

Comment: @Vin05 There still was a bug in my code, so modified answer, again. Should be all right now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code aroun the 19th line. You wrote:

```
if(from_value < to_value) {
   args.IsValid = false; 
   sender.errormessage = "To date must be greater than or equal to the from date"; 
}
```

But you definitely want that `from_value` is smaller then `to_value`. Fix it!

Comment: Oh. ya thanks, I fixed this now, but my code still not working. its failing in data type check(isValidDate function). Even if i enter the  correct date, its is showing error.

Comment: Change your regexp. var regexp = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;